# How do I generate and show random text from database with Meteor.JS

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I want to show a single sentence from the mongodb at a time while a button is clicked. I
Here's my Javascript.

```
import {Template} from 'meteor/templating';
import './body.html';
import { Infos } from '../api/tasks.js';


Template.body.helpers({
  infos() {
    return Infos.find({});
  },
});
    var information=[
            {info:"বাঙলার শেষ স্বাধীন নবাব সিরাজ ভাই"},
            {info:"বাঙলার শেষ স্বাধীন নবাব সিরাজ vai"},
            {info:"বাঙলার শেষ স্বাধীন নবাব সিরাজ ghai"},

        ];

        console.log(information[0].info);

        var i=0;

Template.body.events({

    "click .next"(event){
            const target=event.target;
            const text=target.text;


    $("#mainbody").text(information[i].info);   
            i++;
            if(i>=information.length){
                i=0;
            }
    }
});
```

From array I have been able to show that but I can't do it using Mongodb. Also, is it necessary to use Template.helpers({}) ? because I am still able to pass data from Template.body.events({}).

Answer (score 0):

Put some Quotes inside your Collection.

Query it this way :

```
var count  = Quote.find({}).count();
return Quote.findOne({},{skip:  Math.floor((Math.random() *count ) });
```